# WPF datagrid not updating contents until I move the scrollbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, observablecollection

So I'm trying to populate a datagrid with a list that will automatically update when the list changes. I set the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection, and it works, except the datagrid values won't actually update until I move the scrollbar. How can I make the datagrid update immediately without any kind of interference? I only scroll to the bottom of the list and click a button which adds to the collection. The odd part is that if I use the filter I implemented to find items in the list, it *will* automatically update if I add while it's being filtered (with no scroll bar since it's shorter... related?)

Here are all of the parts that I can imagine being relevant:

In the MainWindow file I set the ItemsSource:

```
ProcessBox.ItemsSource = Manager.ProcessList;
```

Here's where I create the ObservableCollection property. Might it be related to the setter?

```
    public ObservableCollection<ProcessContainer> ProcessList
    {
        get { return processList; }
        set { processList = value; }
    }
```

On the button click I have this bit of code:

```
        Manager.ProcessList.Add(new ProcessContainer("Test", 5, 5));
```

This is the search filter that I apply to the collection when text is entered:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ProcessBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

And the actual filtering method:

```
    private bool ProcessFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterInput.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((item as ProcessContainer).ProcessName.IndexOf(FilterInput.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }
    }
```

Here is the xaml:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessBox" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,0,33" CanUserReorderColumns="False" MinColumnWidth="50" CanUserResizeRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Memory" Binding="{Binding Memory}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is really all there is that I can see having any effect on it. Nothing else touches the parts involved.

Comment: There won't be any help unless you post your code

Comment: I'll try to piece together the relevant parts.

Comment: please post xaml code too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an ObservableCollection ensures that the DataGrid is notified about items that are added or removed from the collection.
From your description I understand that you want to see updates to fields inside items in the collection - in order to do this, you should make the items implement INotifypropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged event when properties are updated.

[INotifyPropertyChanged in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This accomplished what I needed. This question I think is ultimately a duplicate since I didn't realize that changing the scrollbar was actually updating the itemssource (I think, anyway!). I'll accept this anyway but I submitted a duplicate vote.